# Dockerfile Script for Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework, playframework-2.0, docker

I want to launch my Web application (Play 2.2 App) on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk. The Play Application is a self-contained myApp.zip archive.

My Docker-Archive contains:
-myApp.zip (contains the start-file under myApp.zip/myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/myApp)
-Dockerfile with the following script:

> FROM dockerfile/java
>   ADD myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip /usr/local/myApp
>   WORKDIR /usr/local/myApp
>   RUN myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/myApp
>   EXPOSE 9000

I get the following error:

> Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: fabd24 Removing intermediate container f653f7395124 Step 3 : RUN myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/myApp ---> Running in b9e18d52cc99 2014/10/31 10:51:52 Cannot mkdir: /usr/local/myApp is not a directory. Check snapshot logs for details.

It seems like the second line (ADD ...) doesn't have any effect. I also cannot find the /usr/local/myApp directory when I connect to the node over SSH. What is wrong?

Comment: This may be a dumb suggestion but in the docs for ADD they use the example with a trailing slash for destination dir. Would  /usr/local/myApp/ work?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a zip file and treating it like a directory.  You need to unzip it first.

```
ADD myApp.zip /usr/local/myApp.zip
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN unzip /usr/local/myApp.zip
```

Comment: I changed my file to FROM dockerfile/java
RUN mkdir /usr/local/myApp
ADD myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip /usr/local/myApp/myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
WORKDIR /usr/local/myApp 
RUN unzip /usr/local/myApp.zip
EXPOSE 9000 ; but I even don't see the /usr/local/myApp directory :((

Comment: WORKDIR /usr/local.  There is no myApp directory yet :)

Comment: Why? The second line is RUN mkdir /usr/local/myApp . I don't understand it

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  You need RUN unzip /usr/local/myApp/myApp-1.0.SNAPSHOT.zipp